# Reledmac and Very Big Footnotes

Tags: footnotes, memoir, reledmac

I'm writing a commentary on some manuscript.

Since it's not small as footnotes, and I'm trying to keep it in footnote so that I get running text above and running commentary below.

Sometimes, the footnote (commentary) becomes bigger than a page. In such cases, the text is thrown to a new page and the footnote starts on that page. It leaves plenty of space on previous page without use.

Since I'm planning to get this ready for being printed as a book, and they don't want commentary thrown as endnotes, I've to make this thing look like a book, i.e., no waste of paper. The text must capture most of space, is the goal.

I think that customizing how the break occurs for big footnotes (specially in case if they are not far away in sentence) will solve this.

I need some help to figure it out.

MWE is here.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[paperheight=8.3in,paperwidth=5.8in,heightrounded,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parapparatus]{reledmac}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
        \lineation{page}
        \flushbottom%doesn't work either
    \beginnumbering
\pstart
\lipsum[5-10]
Idm \edtext{na}{%
    \Afootnote{%
        \lipsum[7-11]
    }%
} Bvitum\edtext{arhtI}{\Afootnote{\lipsum[1-5]}}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

This is a sample of what is happening in my original project.

[image: happening]

`\raggedbottom` takes all text to top and footnotes stuck to it, but amount of text and footnotes stays same and white space just goes to bottom of page.

This is exact output from the provided MWE. Please, observe how left side bottom has undesired white space and footnote prefers to start on next page dragging the text to other page.

[image]

Comment: i don't reproduce your problem with your ECM. Which version of reledmac do you use ?

Comment: The version is v2.32.1.

I'm adding exact output from provided MWE in OP. Please, find there.

Comment: ok, that is what i got, but that is not what you first show

Comment: i tried without reledmac and with normal \footnote > the problem is the same. I think it is a limit of tex breaking page mechanism.

Comment: @Maïeul Thanks for checking and confirming. So, it appears that we can not produce anything similar to what I expect and what is being published in India as 'with commentary edition'.

Any more suggestions to get the desired output?

Comment: If we allow ```\newpage``` after the text which contains first long footnote (like ```\lipsum[5-10]
 Idm \edtext{na}{%
  \Afootnote{%
   \lipsum[7-11]
  }%
 }\newpage Bvitum\edtext{arhtI}{\Afootnote{\lipsum[1-5]}}```) then the left page gets more text and the footnote also starts on the same page. Other words having footnote attached go to next page and footnote starts there.
It appears acceptable to a certain extent.

I'll like to allow footnotes start on same page where anchor text exists or on the facing page. This will allow me to not break a sentence to two pages.

Comment: an other solution is to use the `\edtextlater` and  `\edtextnow` mechanism to delay the printing. But, more globally, I think that a commentary that is greater than the text itself should not be put as footnote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99742/discussion-between-lalitaalaalitah-and-maieul).

Comment: @Maïeul Just to clarify: Are you saying that the commentary should not be typeset as a footnote and there's some other mechanism in reledmac that should be used, or did you mean reledmac should not be used at all for this and one should find an alternative solution?

Comment: i think that it should not be typeset as a footnote, if it is so big.

Comment: @Maïeul Then how should it be typeset? If I understand correctly the OP just wants a way to typeset their book (text and commentary), and is not attached to typesetting the commentary as a footnote.

Comment: maybe parallel typesetting while be the most easy way.

Comment: @Maïeul I've one solution in my mind. But, it may be tricky.
Instead of making commentary as footnote, we can put the text to be commented upon in footnote. That text is small in size.
But, I'll then like to interchange the position of body text and footnote, so that the text to be commented upon comes above the commentary.
Although, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: hum... should your text been continueed. Maybe a solution would be to alternate between text and commentaries, as it is made in some editions.

Comment: @Maïeul the continuity of text is not a requirement. Text and commentary, both must appear related, and there should be least amount of white space.

Comment: @Maïeul I couldn't find any package which supports typing in parallel rows. And even if we find some package, the challenge will be to keep text and start off related commentary on same page automatically.

Comment: you have reledpar, which do exactly that....

Comment: @Maïeul I just started with reledpar. It's manual says that it can typeset parallel only in either columns or facing pages. I was willing to get something to typeset in parallel rows.
Any suggestion for customization?

Comment: no sorry, no way, for now, without many time.