# Reledmac : convert critical footnotes to critical endnotes

Tags: footnotes, reledmac

I have typed a whole book(text + commentary) with reledmac expecting that it will allow me to get the book which looks something like [this](https://ia601601.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/2/items/in.ernet.dli.2015.486816/2015.486816.Bhamati_jp2.zip&file=2015.486816.Bhamati_jp2/2015.486816.Bhamati_0462.jp2&scale=4&rotate=0).

However, due to some basic problems with LaTeX, it appears to be impossible at this time. It was revealed in [this discussion.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511491/reledmac-and-very-big-footnotes)

So, now my requirement is to convert all critical footnotes to critical endnotes.

I know how to convert normal footnotes to normal endnotes with help of

```
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=endnote
```

But, it doesn't work for critical footnotes.
Does any command exist which can automate this process?

The second solution may be to use `pandoc` to convert the tex to docx, or something similar and then put manually in `InDesign`, etc. But, pandoc can't understand custom commands which I created for my project.
Is it possible to 'teach' pandoc to convert custom commands?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: normally, \let\Aendnote=\Afootnote should work. Which message do you get wrong ?

Comment: Thanks, for the hint. 
To be honest, I didn't have any idea how to do that with critical notes.
It works now. It saved whole problem to extract footnotes and compile with non-LaTeX software or with pandoc.
BTW, I was getting maxsize exceeded, or something like that.
I think at least my book can be published now.
Thanks.
BTW, if you have time please look at the Sanskrit page sample which I provided in OP. This is how Sanskrit texts with commentaries were printed. 
If possible, please accommodate some way to create such texts with LaTeX and reledmac.

Comment: @Maïeul There appears to be a problem. If the lemma was bold then the converted critical endnote is coming all bold. How can we avoid this?
This was not the problem when using them as critical footnotes.

Comment: please open an issue on github.